# beaufitul soup extract cycle

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to extract cities data from ALL pages from below website. I have below code, but cycle keeps running and extracts data over and over again. Looks like Im missing something, can you help

```
cities = []
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    page = 1
    while True:
        url = f'https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/{page}'
        response = session.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        new_comments = [
            cities.find_next_sibling('div').text.strip()
            for cities in soup.find_all('div', text=re.compile('Stadt'))
        ]
        cities += new_comments
        print(cities)
        page += 1
#print(cities)
```

Comment: You do not have an exit condition in your code. You need to `break` when `page==99` or something along those lines. Also I don't know the structure of the website you are scraping but it looks like the page number doesn't change the results?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an exit condition. You need to `break` from the loop at some point.

For example:

```
cities = []
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    page = 1
    while True:
        if page >= 99:
            break
        url = f'https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/{page}'
        response = session.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        new_comments = [
            cities.find_next_sibling('div').text.strip()
            for cities in soup.find_all('div', text=re.compile('Stadt'))
        ]
        cities += new_comments
        print(cities)
        page += 1

print(cities)  # this will print after 98 pages
```

Comment: we could have more than 100 pages. And it also keeps duplicating every city 2 times

Answer (score 0):

Check the `status code of the response` if not **200** break from loop.

I would suggest use css selector to search for item.

**Code:**

```
cities = []
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    page = 1
    while True:
        url = 'https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/{}'.format(page)
        print(url)
        response = session.get(url)
        if response.status_code!=200:
             break
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        new_comments = [
            cities.find_next_sibling('div').text.strip()
            for cities in soup.select('.review-details.user-content.hidden-xs div.text-uppercase:contains(Stadt)')
        ]
        print(new_comments)
        cities += new_comments
        #print(cities)
        page += 1


print(cities)
```

On Console you can see your url and cities.

```
https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/1
['Wolfsburg', 'Salzgitter', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Kassel', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg']
https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/2
['Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Kassel', 'braunschweig', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Zwickau']
https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/3
['Dresden', 'Emden', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Hamburg']
https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/4
['Emden', 'Hannover', 'Wolfsburg', 'Hannover', 'Kassel', 'Hamburg', 'Baunatal', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Emden']
https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/5
['Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Osnabrück', 'Kassel', 'Wolfsburg', 'braunschweig']
https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/6
['Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Kassel', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Kassel', 'Berlin', 'Wolfsburg', 'Emden']
https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/7
['Emden', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Kassel', 'braunschweig', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg']
https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/8
['Kassel', 'Wolfsburg', 'Salzgitter', 'Salzgitter', 'Wolfsburg', 'Kassel', 'Wolfsburg', 'Kassel', 'Wolfsburg', 'Wolfsburg']
```

---

**EDIT**:

```
cities = []
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    page = 1
    while True:
        url = 'https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/{}'.format(page)
        print(url)
        response = session.get(url)
        # if response.status_code!=200:
        #      break
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        if soup.select_one("ul.review-info span[itemprop='itemReviewed']").find_next('span').text=="30.Jan. 2008":
             break
        new_comments = [
            cities.find_next_sibling('div').text.strip()
            for cities in soup.select('.review-details.user-content.hidden-xs div.text-uppercase:contains(Stadt)')
        ]
        print(new_comments)
        cities += new_comments
        #print(cities)
        page += 1


print(cities)
```

Comment: it keeps extracting, cycle not ends

Comment: after how many pages you would like to exit from your code?so that I can update the same.

Comment: all pages, volkswagen is just example, for mercedes for example we could have more/less pages

Comment: @codecodecode : looks like for volkswagen after 159 pages its repeating the last page only.so you need to check whether the last date reach or not.Try edited code.